# How to center scale (rotate) a UIImage in a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, cgaffinetransform

I need to center and scale a UIImage in a UIImageView with contentMode UIViewContentModeTopLeft by only using CGAffineTransform. I can not use contentMode UIViewContentModeCenter because i need the complete CGAffineTransform information.

So far i am using something like this where _imageView is a UIImageView and image a UIImage.

```
_imageView.image = image;
CGFloat scale = fmaxf(_imageView.bounds.size.width / _imageView.image.size.width, _imageView.bounds.size.height / _imageView.image.size.height);
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, _imageView.image.size.width * 0.5, _imageView.image.size.height * 0.5);
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale);    
_imageView.transform = transform;
```

The scaling is ok but the image has always some offset to the bottom right.
Does anybody know how to do this without using contentMode UIViewContentModeCenter?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
CABasicAnimation *scaleAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
scaleAnim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];
scaleAnim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 1.0)];
scaleAnim.removedOnCompletion = YES;
[_imageView.layer addAnimation:scaleAnim forKey:nil];
```

Comment: You can also try playing with the CALayer its [anchorPoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW15).